# Regex - Grabbing each word after a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to grab each each "word" (space being the boundary) after FOO

```
   FOO foo bar foo.bar
```

n.b. There may be spaces before FOO

Comment: Could you provide an example output for this input?

Comment: So you want to match just `foo` since that is the only word after `FOO and space`?

Answer (score 0):

`FOO (([\w\.]+) ?)+`

The inner parenthesis should match each "word". If the "words" can contain any other special symbols you'll need to add those to the list `[\w\.]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$str = 'FOO foo bar foo.bar';
$words = explode(' ',preg_replace('/^(( *)FOO( *))/', '', $str));
```

Now, you have an array ($words) with 3 elements : "foo", "bar" and "foo.bar". I hope I understood !

Comment: That's assuming there's no surrounding text.

Comment: Yes, thanks ! I thought there's no surrounding text, because he says : "There may be spaces before FOO" and nothing else. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Yeah, that is a rather odd statement.. Your code works fine if spaces are indeed the only character that can precede FOO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way with preg_match() and explode().

```
$string = "blah blah     FOO foo bar foo.bar";
preg_match("#.*FOO +(.+ ?)+#ms",$string,$m);
$words = explode(" ",$m[1]);
print_r($words);

Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => foo.bar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this assuming FOO will always be 4 chars (including space) at the beginning of the string.

```
$string = '     FOO foo bar foo.bar';
$everything_after_FOO = explode(' ', substr(trim($string), 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

With `preg_match_all()`:

```
/(?:.*FOO | )([^ ]+)/
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ...
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
        [2] => foo.bar
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:^(?>[^F]++|F(?!OO\h))*+FOO\h++|\h++)\K\H++~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```